# Disabled Options in Xilinx Vivado

Tags: digital-logic, xilinx, vivado

I have two questions.

Firstly, I am trying to make a 4 bit counter on Vivado 2014.3. I have realized that when i tried to simulate the VHDL code, the "Run Post-Synthesis Functional Simulation" and "Run Post-Synthesis Timing Simulation" options are disabled. Do you have any idea to enable them or is this a normal situation? I have shown below.

[image]

My second question is related to that when i am trying to add source, the "Next" button is disabled also. Do you have an idea about this or is it a normal situation. I have shown below.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Post-synthesis stuff meaning it is done after synthesis. Run the synthesis first. As for the second question, having the "Finish" button enabled is hinting that it is the last step. Hit it!

Comment: Which particular Xilinx chip did you select for your exercise?

Comment: Artix-7 xc7a100tcsg324-1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps, but I found the following guide that seems to go through all the basic steps for Vivado.  It helped me, the one from Xilinx... left a lot to be desired.

https://eewiki.net/display/LOGIC/Xilinx+Vivado+Design+Suite+-+Getting+Started